# Passport Talent Family visa application requirement

Tags: working-visas, immigration, france, paperwork, dependent-visa

I am residing in France and have a passport talent card salarie qualifie / enterprise innovante. But my wife is currently residing in Bangladesh. She will need a passport talent family card for which she took an appointment in the French embassy in Bangladesh. My question is what are the documents she needs to submit there for this ? We've tried calling or emailing the embassy but it's in vain (no response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website https://www.welcometofrance.com/en/sheet/accompanying-family-simplified-procedure provides an indicative list of documents to be submitted with an application for a multi-year residence permit under the ‘accompanying family’ procedure https://www.welcometofrance.com/app/uploads/List-of-documents-Accompanying-family.pdf

Applying from outside France, the documents recommended are:

- Long-stay visa application form (CERFA n°14571*05) dated duly completed and signed;
- France-Visas receipt;
- A currently valid passport issued within the last 10 years and valid for at least three months after the visa
  expiry date;
- Proof of parentage/marriage: copy of full birth certificate or copy of the marriage certificate;
- Three recent standardized passport photos;
- Spouse’s or parent’s multi-year residence permit issued by the French authorities or Identity card (ID).

Note that the list is caveated:

> Make sure you contact the consular, diplomatic or prefectoral authority that will be handling your application to obtain a list of required documents appropriate to your personal circumstances and the reason for your stay in France

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for